# Type error: Cannot find module '@sanity/vision' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: next.js, sanity

[image]

./sanity/sanity.config.ts:3:26
Type error: Cannot find module '@sanity/vision' or its corresponding type declarations.
1 | import {defineConfig} from 'sanity'
2 | import {deskTool} from 'sanity/desk'

> 3 | import {visionTool} from '@sanity/vision'
> |                          ^
> 4 | import {schemaTypes} from './schemas'
> 5 |
> Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

This is the error im getting while deploying it to vercel. Local host running fine but it is sgiving error while uploading on vercel/ Deployment.

To deploy it successfully on vercel

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error for my predeployed project so I used following command which worked:

vercel deploy --prebuilt

I used it in administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the problem here is that when deploying on vercel and trying to resolve the modules in `sanity.config.ts`, it can't find the modules as they aren't added in the nextjs `packag.json`, so they aren't installed during next build.
The solution was to include sanity packages in the nextjs `package.json` dependancies.

Check out this [thread](https://www.sanity.io/answers/error-deploying-project-to-vercel-due-to-missing-module-sanity-cli) on sanity.io

Answer (score -1):

the solution that worked for me was the following:

basically copy

```
"sanity": "^3.0.0" ,
"styled-components": "^5.2.0",
"@sanity/vision": "^3.5.0"
```

in `dependencies` and `"@sanity/eslint-config-studio": "^2.0.1"` in `devDependencies` in next `package.json`, run `npm install` in next project(not sanity).